# Android Retrofit | Post custom object (send json to server)

Tags: android, json, post, laravel

I was wondering how could I go about sending a custom object to my API using retrofit, something like this:

```
@POST(URL_ORDERS)
public void newOrder(Order order, Callback<Boolean> success);
```

Here's how I'd parse it on my server

```
public function store()
    {
    if(Auth::check()){
        $order = Input::get();
        $table = $order->table;
        $items = $order->items;

        if(!$table->taken){
            $table->taken = true;

            $order->push();
            $table->push();

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

For some reason I'm getting

```
06-04 20:45:59.275    6085-6306/com.tesis.restapp.restapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aae210)
06-04 20:45:59.285    6085-6306/com.tesis.restapp.restapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Retrofit-Idle
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RestAppApiInterface.newOrder: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
            at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.methodError(RestMethodInfo.java:120)
            at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parameterError(RestMethodInfo.java:124)
            at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseParameters(RestMethodInfo.java:443)
            at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.init(RestMethodInfo.java:131)
```

I guess what I want it do to is to somehow transform my object into a json and send it to my server. Am I approaching this the right way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The error is from not providing the `@Body` annotation on your `Order` parameter.  Change it to:

```
@POST(URL_ORDERS)
public void newOrder(@Body Order order, Callback<Boolean> success);
```

Retrofit uses [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/%20Gson) to serialize and deserialize JSON by default.  Gson uses variable names by default for serialization, but they can be changed using the annotation `@SerializedName("replacement_name")`.

For Example, If your `Order` class looked like this:

```
public class Order {
    @SerializedName("custom_id")
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Item> items;
}

public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

Then Gson would automatically serialize that to

```
{
    "custom_id": 1,
    "name": "Hello Object",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Hello Item"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: right! :) that's what I figured. I don't know why the error though :/ (my Order class looks almost exactly as the one you wrote)

Comment: What if a List<Order> were to be sent?

Comment: @JamesMcCracken You cannot provide /@Body if you are providing /@Query annotations.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky what if we need to have both query and body annotations?

Comment: @JamesMcCracken can you please tell me how to get the value of order on server using getParameter() method in servlet?

Comment: In my case it works after adding content-type to header of the post request: @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")