# Retrofit post request with complex data

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I want to to make a POST request using Retrofit. My POST request has a body which is complex data like this

```
{
    "user": {
        "personal_info": {
            "first_name": "Walter",
            "last_name": "White",
            "date_of_birth": "1972-01-03 00:00:00 PST"
        },
        "address_info": {
            "address_1": "308 NEGRA ARROYO LANE",
            "address_2": "#",
            "city": "ALBUQUERQUE",
            "state": "NM",
            "zip_code": "87104"
        },
        "contact_info": {
            "email": "wwhite@test.com",
            "telephone": "88888888888",
            "telephone_type_id": 1
        },
        "employment_info": {
            "employer_name": "SELF",
            "employment_status_id": 7,
            "annual_income": 9000000000000000,
            "monthly_income": 750000000000,
            "employment_start_year": 0,
            "employment_start_month": 0
        }
    }
}
```

I have the interface defined as

```
@POST("/users")
void user(@Body User User, Callback<User> cb);
```

I am not sure how my User class should look like, I want the payload to be same as mentioned above,
   I Am confused how to send this type of data server and how to store data in user class

Comment: this data is not coming from server. i have to send this data to server

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/24049504/8089770

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46388917/8089770

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to think about the structure provided as a Json response.

Just use some smart tools like [jsonscheme2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) will automatically generate the class files for you.

you just need to visit the site and configure your requirement like package name, class name, set target language **JAVA**, source type **JSON** , annotation style **Gson** and then click on **Zip** button (You can also see the preview by click on preview button).

After click on **Zip** button the zip will be downloading automatically. extract the zip and you will find your class files.

Comment: thats not json response